# Someway to tag a photo with a facebook page with iOS API

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I was trying to tag a photo with a fanpage, but I only succeed tagging users on the photo.

Later I found in the Facebook API reference that "...Currently, you cannot tag a Page in a photo using this API." and I got mad!

So I'm here to aks you guys. is there anyway to tag a page in a photo? ANYWAY?!

After being hopeless and crying a lot, I got an idea, "i'll use the web Facebook API with iOS". But I really don't know whether it will solve my problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct, according to this [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/), "you cannot tag a Page in a photo using this API."

If the engineers took the time to specifically mention that, then this is by design and it is not possible.